# Android client using XML-messages

Tags: android, xml, client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reading XML from a URL in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854650/how-to-reading-xml-from-a-url-in-android)

The idea is to make an Android application, which would work with an existing server sending XML-messages and getting XML-responses.

Here's the code:

```
try {
                URL url1 = null;
                url1 = new URL("http://mysite.com/");
                URLConnection urlc1 = url1.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) urlc1;

                con1.setRequestMethod("POST");

                con1.setUseCaches(false);
                con1.setDoOutput(true);
                con1.setDoInput(true);
                con1.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
                con1.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


                XmlSerializer ser1 = Xml.newSerializer();
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                ser1.setOutput(writer);
                ser1.startDocument("UTF-8", true);              
                ser1.startTag("", "request");
                ser1.attribute("", "query", "open_session");
                ser1.startTag("", "");
                ser1.attribute("", "client", "name");
                ser1.attribute("", "version", "1.0");
                ser1.endTag("", "");
                ser1.endTag("", "request");
                ser1.endDocument();

                String query = writer.toString();   

                con1.connect();

                OutputStreamWriter out1 = new OutputStreamWriter(con1.getOutputStream());  
                out1.write(query);  
                out1.flush();   


                String result1 = null;
                BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con1.getInputStream()));
                 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                 String line;
                 while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null){
                     sb.append(line);
                     }
                 br1.close();
                 result1 = sb.toString();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The program opens the connection, creates a login request XML, sends it to the server and gets XML-answer.

But it does not work properly. The response I get is:

```
<html><head><title>302 Found</title></head></body bg color="white"><center><h1>302 Found</h1></center><hr><center>nginx/1.0.0</center></body><html>
```

And that's not a listed error from the server. The successful answer should be:

```
<result success="true">
<session-info time-out="number" id="number" start="number"/>
</result>
```

It's interesting, that when I comment this part of the code:

```
OutputStreamWriter out1 = new OutputStreamWriter(con1.getOutputStream());  
out1.write(query);  
out1.flush();
```

I get the proper XML-error answer:

```
<result success="false">
<error error-code="XML-01">
Wrong XML
</error>
</result>
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check complet demo http://stackoverflow.com/a/12856655/1487822

Answer (score 0):

`302 Found` is a redirect message and if you are using the `HttpClient`,  it can handle these redirects internally.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2560129/1321873 to get an overview of how you can post an XML to a server. (Although they are sending a SOAP XML, the mechanism for sending a plain XML is also the same - just change the content-type)

Comment: Thank you for the redirection hint, managed it with the service holder. But now I have another problem. According to the logs server doesn't receive my XML. I was told that I should use CGI, but I have no idea how to. Could you advise smth?

Comment: Can you please post it as a new question?

Comment: did it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074411/android-client-not-sending-xml-to-the-server